# Why does this for loop in assembly loop so many times?

Tags: loops, assembly, x86

The question in the book shows the following loop:

```
    mov ecx, -1
forD: .
      .                ; loop body
      .
      loop forD
```

The question asks *"how many times is each loop body executed?"*

The answer in the back of the book says 4,294,967,295, but why? What's the significance of this number? Is this supposed to be a never-ending-loop?

Comment: If you wanted to write a never-ending loop, you'd `jmp forD` to unconditionally branch, instead of using a conditional branch on a loop counter.  The `loop` instruction is only useful for code-size optimization in a few special cases, and on Intel CPUs is slower than a normal dec/jnz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-1 is 0xFFFFFFFF in 32-bit [2's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), which is 4294967295 (2<sup>32</sup> - 1) in unsigned decimal

The loop time depends on the loop body. But in current CPUs you can run a short loop several billion times within a few seconds or less

Comment: So if the -1 was, for example the other questions in the text: 10, 1, and 0, then the loop would repeat 10, 1, and 0 time respectively?

Comment: yes. You should read the function of the loop instruction in Intel's manual

Comment: The question is about the iteration count, not performance.  But yes, even CPUs where [the `loop` instruction is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742570/why-is-the-loop-instruction-slow-couldnt-intel-have-implemented-it-efficiently) (everything except recent AMD) can run it in a *few* seconds, vs. about 1 second for a normal `dec ecx/jnz` loop on a 4.3GHz CPU.

Answer (score 3):

`loop` works as follows:

1. decrement `(e)cx` by 1
2. check if it is 0
3. if not, jump to the specified offset/label
4. if 0, continue with the next instruction

`-1` equals to `4294967295 unsigned`, which in turn results in that number of loop iterations.

There are some catches using `loop`:

- `Loop` *first* decreases the counter register.Putting there `0` will not result in zero repetitions but in `4294967296`, because the first decreasing will result in `-1` in `(e)cx`. Accordingly, putting 1 there will result in zero *repetitions*. Please note that this still executes the looped instructions once - if the loop destination is before the loop instruction.
- `Loop` is a 2byte opcode. First byte is `E2` for the instruction itself, so there is only one byte left for jump destination offset. That offset is signed, so you can only loop within -128..127 bytes distance.